# Java get correct method return value in parallel execution environment

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I have two methods which can execute in parallely in my java class. Imagine method a calls getList method by passing fileA and gets the String list returned by getList method and method b calls getList method by passing fileB and acquires the List returned by getList.(Those list would be the contents of appropriate file as passed by the caller)

```
public void a(){
List<String> list = getList(fileA);

    for(String s: list){
       //Analyse list and do something here 
    }
}

public void b(){
    List<String> list = getList(fileB);

    for(String s: list){
       //Analyse list and do something here 
    }
}

public List<Stirng> getList(File file){

    //Read lines in the file in to an array list

    //Return List 
}
```

In a parallel method execution scenario, as I think this can be fall in to a situation like follows,
in a half way reading fileA by getList method b gets invoked and it tries to read fileB using the same getList method.

I want to clarify that in a such scenario does JVM guarantees that we are getting correct results for the calls from method a and method b ?

If not how can I handle such scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `JVM` guarantee different thread methods call the same method will not be affected?

The `JVM` has [Runtime Data Area](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5), Per thread will create it's own ***data area*** when they started, and these ***data areas*** will be destroyed when thread existed. so when thread's method execute, they will use it's own data area, and without affects the other thread's call.

If `getList` will cause ***`side effect`***, you need to `lock` it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try put some sort of synchronization mechanisms in getList(File) and test it out?

public synchronized getList(file){}

Answer (score 0):

If there is no write happening, calling the same method will not affect the previous call. Why do you think it should? This is not relevant to JVM in particular but programming in general.